# ASP MVC Simple Routing Optional Parameter

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a couple of routes in my config that seem to work OK in the IIS express dev environment, but not in IIS. I can get to the route `BlogArchive` route, but not the `BlogDetail`route.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BlogDetail",
            url: "Blog/{Slug}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Detail", slug = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BlogArchive",
            url: "Blog",
            defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" }
        );
```

This can be fixed by just adding an additional pointer to the `BlogDetail` i.e. making the whole url map to `Blog/Entry/{Slug}`, but I would rather not have to have that extra bit. I can't seem to find any examples on the web, so excuse me if I am missing something simple.

Comment: What URL are you trying?

Comment: In this situation I believe slug should not be UrlParameter.Optional.  I also noticed the case is different on {Slug} although I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: I have tried http://root/blog this works.... but http://root/blog/anything-at-all returns not found from IIS.

Comment: If not UrlParameter.Optional then do I need anything else in this description?

Comment: You should just be able to remove 'slug = UrlParameter.Optional'.  And, of course, make sure your Detail action is public and takes a parameter named Slug.  If that doesn't work I'll give it a test here.

Comment: Perfect.... I thought I had tried this before and needed to ask the question. But it works fine. I ought to remove the question really, not much good to others.